# Splashing of Falling Sphere does not depend on Sphere Size

Tags: fluid-dynamics, experimental-physics

I am reading through a [Nature article](https://archive.org/details/arxiv-cond-mat0701093/page/n1/mode/2up) where the authors study whether a sphere dropped from height into a body of water has enough velocity to splash and form the classic effect where air is pulled in behind the sphere (seen in Figure 1(b)).

In the article, it is stated that changing the size of the sphere does not affect the threshold for 'cavity' formation when the sphere splashes during impact and entrains air ie. if you identify the velocity needed for the sphere to splash, the velocity will not change if the sphere size is changed.

No explanation is given for this so is this just obvious that this would happen (because a smaller sphere will just displace a smaller amount of fluid and the threshold is not affected)?  I find this slightly surprising, I am just wondering if this is still true for example if one has a sphere which is 1mm or 2mm, is it not possible that it could be so small that it would just slip through the surface without splashing and entraining air when the larger sphere does splash?

Edit: To be clear, having read similar studies where one instead has a droplet which falls on a flat solid surface and splashes or does not splash, it seems that the radius of the droplet does matter, so I am just confused as to why it would not matter for a solid sphere falling into a liquid, which is surely very similar apart from different boundary conditions.

Comment: I am guessing that the formation of air cavity may have to do with the time available for draining away the entrapped air (at the front of the falling sphere), which time is determined primarily by the velocity with which the sphere enters the fluid.

Comment: It's possible although I am not sure.  So as the sphere drops, the higher velocity somehow traps the air directly in front of it which leads to the cavity formation, as higher speed means it is harder for the molecules to ''get out of the way'' of the sphere?

Comment: I can't be sure either, that was my best guess. Whenever two solid objects collide, obviously the air in the gap between them must be completely drained away before actual contact occurs. When one of the objects is fluid, its body can deform around the solid body, and contact can occur in a way that pockets of air are trapped without having been completely drained away.